# 12.04 LTS updated today and now throws me back to login screen after logging in

Tags: 12.04, login, password, lts

I allowed the update to run and once it finished, I restarted.  Now it will not accept my password.  I can log in as a guest, but can not access most of my programs or files.  Additionally, when I enter my password, it seems to begin the login process but after the screen flashing black (there are some lines displayed but it flashes too rapidly to see) the system returns me to the log in screen.

I tried logging in in terminal and this is the error I get:

```
Last login: Fri Feb 1 09:15:55 EST 2013 on tty1    
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-37-generic x86_64) 

 * Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/

[1] keyct1_search: Required key not available Perhaps try the interactive 'encryptfs-mount-private'
```

I am a purely cut/paste user.  This is really getting to be an issue.  For each of the past three updates that required a restart, my system has failed to restart for a variety of reasons...

How can I fix this?

Comment: When you say the boot process begins after you enter your password, this is a normal login, right? Isn't the system already booted up?

Comment: It is the normal log on.  I can click on the icon to select  Gnome, Gnome Classic, Recovery Console, Ubuntu, Ubuntu 2D, XBMC, etc... but no matter the option chosen, it starts to log in/boot and immediately ends up back at the log in screen/prompt

Comment: Here is the screen shot of my machine: http://imgur.com/HaRKVxJ

Comment: Try running "ecryptfs-mount-private" after you login on the console.

Comment: What happens if you [reset the password](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)?

Comment: Please add the contents of `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot and then select previous version in recovery mode. Then go to settings, users and create another administrator and password. Select the new administrator as the default and click the lock button. Restart system and login with new user name and password.